# How to cast boost::exception?

Tags: c++, boost, exception

Consider the following example (taken from https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.exception)

```
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>
#include <exception>
#include <new>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::error_info<struct tag_errmsg, std::string> errmsg_info;

struct allocation_failed : public std::exception
{
  const char *what() const noexcept { return "allocation failed"; }
};

char *allocate_memory(std::size_t size)
{
  char *c = new (std::nothrow) char[size];
  if (!c)
    BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(allocation_failed{});
  return c;
}

char *write_lots_of_zeros()
{
  try
  {
    char *c = allocate_memory(std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max());
    std::fill_n(c, std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max(), 0);
    return c;
  }
  catch (boost::exception &e)
  {
    e << errmsg_info{"writing lots of zeros failed"};
    throw;
  }
}

int main()
{
  try
  {
    char *c = write_lots_of_zeros();
    delete[] c;
  }
  catch (boost::exception &e)
  {
    std::cerr << *boost::get_error_info<errmsg_info>(e);
  }
}
```

The function `allocate_memory()` throws exception using the following statement

```
BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(allocation_failed{});
```

**In the catch block how can I convert `boost::exception &e` back to `allocation_failed`?**

Also, if my code has multiple throw statements like `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(A{})`, `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(B{})`, `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(C{})`, etc. Where A, B, C are classes. Without using boost I can have separate catch blocks for each type of exception, in the following manner.

```
...
catch(A e){
...
}
catch(B e){
...
}
catch(C e){
...
}
```

**How can I do the same when using boost, so that `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(A{})`, `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(B{})`, `BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(C{})`, etc. go to different catch blocks?**

I am new to boost library, and some of its concepts elude me.

Comment: why sticking to boost? (And why not using RAII?)

Comment: I am using an API which throws exception in this manner. I'll have to read about RAII. Will get back after going through it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION` always throws a type which inherits the type of its argument, in addition to inheriting `boost::exception`.  This means two things:

1. You can `dynamic_cast` from `boost::exception` to the type that was passed.

-

```
catch (boost::exception &e)
{
    std::cerr << *boost::get_error_info<errmsg_info>(e);
    if ( allocation_failed* af = dynamic_cast<allocation_failed*>(&e) )
    {
        std::cerr << af->what() << std::endl; // redundant
    }
}
```

2. You can directly catch the type that was passed.  However, you should always catch by reference to avoid slicing.  (This advice is independent of whether you're using boost or whatever.)

-

```
catch (A& a) {
    // ...
} catch (B& b) {
    // ...
} catch (C& c) {
    // ...
}
```

Of course, doing it this way, if you want any of boost's error formatting or extra data, you would need to then `dynamic_cast` the exception object to `boost::exception*`.

Comment: Just to clarify - The exception type that BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION() throws inherits from the type of argument, and from boost::exception. This means that in BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION(A{}) , the thrown type inherits from boost::exception, and A, while the type A itself need not be inherited from boost::exception. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's right.  (Or if `A` does inherit `boost::exception` already, it won't "add another".)